# Class in place of Interface failing

Tags: c#, .net, interface

```
interface I1
{
}
class ClassOfI1 : I1
{
}

interface I2
{
    I1 ABC { get; set; }
}
class ClassOfI2 : I2
{
    public ClassOfI1 ABC { get; set; }
}
```

Throws the following error:

> 'ns.ClassOfI2' does not implement interface member 'ns.I2.ABC'.
>   'ns.ClassOfI2.ABC' cannot implement 'ns.I2.ABC' because it does not
>   have the matching return type of 'ns.I1'.

Why? (And is there a way around this? I want `ClassOfI1` there, not just the interface.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When implementing interfaces, the return types must match exactly. C# does not support return type covariance. Your implementation should therefore be:

```
class ClassOfI2 : I2
{
    public I1 ABC { get; set; }
}
```

Even if it did, your code would be unsafe since you could do:

```
public class Other : I1 { ... }
I2 iface = new ClassOfI2();
iface.ABC = new Other();
```

You might consider using generics:

```
interface I2<T> where T : I1
{
    T ABC { get; set; }
}

class ClassOfI2 : I2<ClassOfI1>
{
    public ClassOfI1 ABC { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: For anyone viewing this answer - I accepted it as the answer, but also posted an answer with a 'workaround' to get the desired results.

Comment: (@) Lee Thanks for your answer. However, your section about my code being unsafe has a typo in it - you meant `... Other : I1...` , right?

Comment: @ispiro - Yes it should be `I1`, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Because your method returns ClassOfI1 instead I1! It should return the interface itself. Later you are allowed to return a concrete class (in this case ClassOfI1) but the definition in the implementation, must match that in the interface!
So change your code to:

```
interface I1
{
}

class ClassOfI1 : I1
{
}

interface I2
{
    I1 ABC { get; set; }
}

class ClassOfI2 : I2
{
    public I1 ABC { get; set; }
}
```

and it should work.

You could always use an instance of ClassOfI1 later in your code, like:

```
var c1 = new ClassOfI1();
var c2 = new ClassOfI2();
c2.ABC = c1;
```

Comment: But it should be possible to substitute the class for the interface. Just as you can use a `List` in place of an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Not at this point - later at some point in code yes, you coud do object.ABC = ClassOfI1Instance, but the method must match the definition of the interface!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it:

```
class ClassOfI2 : I2
{
    ClassOfI1 _ABC;
    public I1 ABC { get { return _ABC; } set { _ABC = (ClassOfI1)value; } }
}
```

Note that this will throw an exception in the case brought by Lee in his answer, but when used with `ClassOfI1`'s only - it runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've just seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21141004/how-to-specify-and-use-a-real-interface/21141082#21141082) and that seems to be the correct way to do this: **generic interfaces**.

The short of it:

Make `ABC`'s Type (in `I2`): **T** `where T: I1`