# How to specify and use a real interface?

Tags: c#

is it possible to specify *real* interfaces which must implement methods with interfaces?`
Or how does this work what i want:

```
public interface IGraph
{
    void addEdge(IGraphVertex a, IGraphVertex b);
}

public interface IGraphVertex
{

}

// problematic code


public class Graph2d : IGraph
{
    public void addEdge(Graph2dVertex a, Graph2dVertex b)
    {

    }
}

public class Graph2dVertex : IGraphVertex
{

}
```

the error i get is that Graph2d doesn't implement `addVertex(IGraphVertex a, IGraphVertex b);`

Comment: method of interfaces uses IGraphVertex, your implementation uses GraphVertex. (Note the missing I)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want a generic interface:

```
public interface IGraphVertex
{

}

public interface IGraph<T>
    where T: IGraphVertex
{
    void addEdge(T a, T b);
}
```

Then:

```
public class Graph2dVertex : IGraphVertex
{

}

public class Graph2d : IGraph<Graph2dVertex>
{
    public void addEdge(Graph2dVertex a, Graph2dVertex b)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to fix the method signature in Graph2h class:

```
public class Graph2d : IGraph
{
   public void addVertex(IGraph2dVertex a, IGraph2dVertex b)
   {

   }
}
```